# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in UIViewcontroller when Method calling from NSObject

Tags: ios, delegates, nsobject

I have a view controller (UserLogin) that calls a method in `NSObject` class (custompop). The method returns a UIView object to `viewController`. In method i add one button and call action `popupAction` on button click. The `popupAction` calls method in view controller. I set all the delegate property.

Here is the code:

```
//**in viewcontroller.h**
#import "custompopup.h"
@interface UserLogin : UIViewController<customPopUpDelegate>
{
custompopup *obj_custompopup;//NSObject Class
}
-(void)handlePopUpAction;


//**in viewcontroller.m**
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
   obj_custompopup = [[custompopup alloc] init];
  [obj_custompopup setDelegate:self];

 popupview = [[UIView alloc] init];
popupview = [obj_custompopup initwithTitleText:@"Title"  withdelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:popupview];
}
 -(void)handlePopUpAction
{
  NSLog(@"Inside handlePopUpAction");
}


//**in NSObject.h**
@protocol customPopUpDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)handlePopUpAction;
@end
@interface custompopup : NSObject
{
id<customPopUpDelegate>delegate;
UIButton *First_Btn;
}
@property(retain)id delegate;


 //**in NSObject.m**
@synthesize delegate;
 -(UIView *)initwithTitleText:(NSString *)titleText  withdelegate:(id)del 
//returns uiview   to viewcontroller
{
self.delegate =del;
UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] init];
customView.frame = CGRectMake(200, 100, 617,367);

First_Btn =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
First_Btn.frame=CGRectMake(20, 330,125,45);
 [First_Btn @"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[First_Btn addTarget:self  action:@selector(popUpAction)       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[customView addSubview:First_Btn];

return customView;
}

-(void)popUpAction
{
[[self delegate] handlePopUpAction];
}
```

Problem is compiler goes in each method successfully and print everything in console till last step. After complete last step in view controller, `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` comes and the application crashes.

Comment: Can you put the log message?

Comment: log messeages are                                                       Inside popUpAction
Inside handlePopUpAction

Comment: The message which is displaying for the crash(if any).

Comment: There is not any msg display for crash

Comment: Could you please let me know what is "obj_custompopuphandler" and it's use.

Comment: it was my printing mistake.I just edit it "obj_custompopuphandler" with "obj_custompopup".

Comment: I've executed your code what you have provided here but it is not crashing.

Answer (score 0):

your init is wrong .. dont get what you try to do but you return customView , leaving self unretained but you are using self.

Comment: i am trying to do custom alertview .In nsobject classs  create one method which return uiview with image and button on it.how to retain self and how to do init